# minimum rectangular surface in square matrix - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

Could someone point me towards a correct approach for the following problem: I have a square matrix (N*N) filled with values of 0 and 1. I need to find two rectangles in the matrix, so they check the following conditions:

1. Every element of 1 from the matrix, must be included in at least one rectangle;
2. The sum of the surfaces of the two rectangles must be minimum(it is permitted that one of the rectangles to have the surface 0).

To be more specific of what a rectangle is: a rectangle is defined by two intervals [a1, b1], [a2, b2], and contains all the matrix cells (i,j) so as a1≤i≤b1 , a2≤j≤b2. To be more clear on what surface means:(b1-a1+1)·(b2-a2+1).

Can you please help me out with some ideas. Thanks a lot.

EDIT1: The two rectangles may overlap.

EDIT2: One of the rectangles is permitted to have the surface 0

Comment: Are the two covering rectangles allowed to overlap? (Please edit answer into question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimal area matrix covering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033951/minimal-area-matrix-covering)

Comment: Duplicate question, but no answer there, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original approach. This doesn't work in the case where the optimal solution requires overlapping rectangles (e.g. a "+" of 1s on a background of 0s).

> 1. Find the minimum bounding rectangle containing all the 1s.
> 2. Your first rectangle extends from the top-left of this bounding rectangle and your second bounding rectangle extends from the
>      bottom-right of this bounding rectangle.
> 3. For each row R between the top and bottom of the bounding rectangle, create candidate rectangles extending from the top to R and
>      from the bottom to R, both the width of the bounding rectangle.
> 4. Reduce both of these candidates so that they are minimum bounding rectangles of the 1s within them. These rectangle pairs all satisfy
>      Point 1. Keep the minimum one over all R.
> 5. Repeat from Step 2 to cover every pair of corners in the overall bounding rectangle and keep the best solution overall.

After several aborted attempts at an efficient solution, each of which failed in certain cases, I think the only approach that will find the best solution is as follows:

You only need to consider the bounding rectangle of the 1s. The two bounding rectangles will not lie outside this region. Suppose the bounding rectangle goes from row (R1, C1) to (R2, C2).

```
    For S1 in R1 to R2
        For S2 in S1 to R2
            For D1 in C1 to C2
                For D2 in D1 to C2
                    Reduce the rectangle (S1, C1)-(S2, C2) to be the minimum bounding rectangle of the 1s it contains
                    Reduce the rectangle (R1, D1)-(R2, D2) to be the minimum bounding rectangle of the 1s it contains that aren't already in the other rectangle. This is a candidate solution.

                    Reduce the rectangle (R1, D1)-(R2, D2) to be the minimum bounding rectangle of the 1s it contains.
                    Reduce the rectangle (S1, C1)-(S2, C2) to be the minimum bounding rectangle of the 1s it contains that aren't already in the other rectangle. This is another candidate solution.
```

Pick the best candidate solution you find.

---

Notes:

- <s>The best solution won't have overlapping rectangles because such a solution could always be improved by reducing one of the rectangles so it no longer overlaps. Hence we only need to pick one R in Step 3 (instead of independent maximum rows for each rectangle).</s>
- It doesn't matter whether you split by row (R) or by column (C), but there's no need to do both. For speed, you might choose rows when the bounding rectangle is short and fat, and columns when it is tall and thin.
- If you find a candidate solution where neither rectangle contains any zeroes then it must be the best solution and you can stop.

Comment: I now realise from looking at the example in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033951/minimal-area-matrix-covering) that my statements about overlapping rectangles were incorrect. I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: Yes, of course there are easy examples where your statement about overlapping rectangles is wrong.  If & when you fix that problem, also estimate run time; eg, your "5. Repeat from Step 2" might lead to an O(N^3) time, or is it O(N^4)?  (The earlier question mentions O(N^4))

Comment: I do not have a limit for the complexity of the problem

Comment: There are always six pairs of corners, so I think it's just a linear multiplier and doesn't affect the big-oh complexity.

Comment: A rectangle is permitted to have the surface 0, so in some cases it may be convenient to find only one rectangle

Comment: I've added a (slower) approach that I think should be guaranteed to find an optimal solution, even if it requires overlapping rectangles.